# SQLite problem "unable to open the database file"

Tags: c#, ipad, sqlite, xamarin.ios

I come to you after a lot of hours googling and reading other discussions about SQLite on StackOverflow, but I definitely can't find any explanation to my problem, so here it is :

- **The context :**
  I'm developping an application for iPad wich has to deal with some "large" amounts of data, in several occasions. In one of them, I must import points coordinates from a .kml file (Google's xml for geographical data) into my database, in order to reuse them later with a MKMapView and load them faster than by parsing xml when it needs to show a specific layer.
- **The details :**
  The import thing is quite easy : when dealing with those files, I'm only concerned with 2 tables :

  - One containing zones definitions and details : for the moment, an `integer` as an id, and a `text` for naming.
  - One containing two `real` for coordinate storage and an `integer` referencing the first table for knowing which zone point is part of.
    So as long as reading my file, I first create an entry for the new zone, and then I insert points into the second table, with ID of the last zone created in the first table...nothing complicated!

  But...
- **The problem :**
  After running fine a while, I get an exception from SQLite with the famous message "Unable to open the database file", and then it comes I can't do anything more with the database. This exception can randomly occur in the zone creation or the points insertion methods.
- **My reflexions :**
  Considering the numerous points in those files, I suspected memory or disk saturation but other parts of my app discarded those points (to my mind).
  First, memory : it comes that when the exception occurs, the app is using about 10 or 12 MB of RAM. It can seems quite huge, but it's due to the ~10MB .kml file loaded in memory, so it's explainable. And above it all, the MKMapView thing of my app deals with tons of high-res tiles layers above map, and so leads to memory peaks which can afford 20 or even 25MB without making the iPad to crash.
  Second, disk : when reseting my database and filling only the 2 tables described above, the db file size when the exception occurs is always about 2.2 or 2.5MB, but when I fill other tables (the other parts of my apps works well!) the db file is about 6 or 7MB, and the device doesn't complain at all.
- **So what?!**
  CPU-angryness and panic? I don't think so because some of the other tables of my database are filled at the same rythm without problem... and running my app in simulator crashes too, with a core i7 just laughing at the job.
  SQLite bad use? There we go! To my mind, it's the only solution left! But I really can't understand what's going on here because I process my requests the same way I do in other app's parts which - repeating myself - work like a charm!
- **SQLite details :**
  I have a `DB` class which is a singleton I use to avoid creating/releasing an `SqliteConnection` object each request I do, and all my methods dealing with database are contained in this class to be sure I don't play with the connection anywhere else without knowing it. Here are concerned methods of this class :

  ```
  public void     saveZone(ObjZone zone)  { //at this point, just creates an entry with a name and let sqlite give it a new id
      lock (connection) { //SqliteConnection object
          try {
              openConnection();
              SqliteCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
              cmd.CommandText = zone.id == 0 ?
                  "insert into ZONES (Z_NAME) values (" + format(zone.name) + ") ;" :
                  "update ZONES set Z_NAME = " + format(zone.name) + " where Z_ID = " + format(zone.id) + " ;";
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              if (zone.id == 0) {
                  cmd.CommandText = "select Z_ID from ZONES where ROWID = last_insert_rowid() ;";
                  zone.id = uint.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
              }
              cmd.Dispose();
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
              Log.failure("DB.saveZone(" + zone.ToString() + ") : [" + e.GetType().ToString() + "] - " +
                  e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace); //custom Console.WriteLine() method with some formating
              throw e;
          }
          finally {
              connection.Close();
          }
      }
  }

  public void     setPointsForZone(List<CLLocationCoordinate2D> points, uint zone_id) { //registers points for a given zone
      lock (connection) {
          try {
              openConnection();
              SqliteCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
              cmd.CommandText = "delete from ZONESPOINTS where Z_ID = " + format(zone_id);
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              foreach(CLLocationCoordinate2D point in points) {
                  cmd.CommandText = "insert into ZONESPOINTS values " +
                      "(" + format(zi_id) + ", " + format(point.Latitude.ToString().Replace(",", ".")) + ", "
                      + format(point.Longitude.ToString().Replace(",", ".")) + ");";
                  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                  cmd.Dispose();
              }
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
              Log.failure("DB.setPointsForZone(" + zone_id + ") : [" + e.GetType().ToString() + "] - " + e.Message);  
              throw e;
          }
          finally {
              connection.Close();
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  And to be as clear as I can, here are some of the methods referenced in the two above (I use this custom `openConnection()` method because I use foreign keys constraints in most of my tables and cascading behaviours are not enabled by default, but I need them.) :

  ```
  void openConnection() {
      try {
          connection.Open();
          SqliteCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
          cmd.CommandText = "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON";
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          cmd.Dispose();
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
          Log.failure("DB.openConnection() : [" + e.GetType().ToString() + "] - " + e.Message);
          throw e;
      }
  }

  public static string format(object o) {
      return "'" + o.ToString().Replace("'", "''") + "'";
  }
  ```

**Well**, sorry for the novel, I may already thank you for reading all that stuff, no?! Anyway, if I missed something that could be useful, let me know and I'll document it as soon as possible. 
I hope someone will be able to help me, anyway, thank you by advance!
(And my apologies for my poor frenchie's english.)

**EDIT**
My problem is "solved"! After a few changes for debugging pourposes, no big modifications, and no success, I put back the code in the state I posted it... and now it works. But I really would appreciate if some someone could give me an explanation of what may have happened! It seems like SQLite behaviour (on iPad at least - never used it anywhere else) can be quite obscure at some times... :/

Comment: Btw, if someone can tell me why the hell StackOverflow won't let me start my post with 'Hello'?! I always thought being polite is the best way to get an answer to a question!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't cross my fingers for this but I would try two things:

1. If possible, pre-process the KML file to a second SQLite database and use this database to import data in the main database (thinking of lower memory/processor requirements)
2. Transaction the imported data in small batches.

HTH

EDIT: you might have checked this already, but anyway: [unable to open database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377488/unable-to-open-database).

Comment: Already checked, but thanks! Your first idea was not bad, but as I'm going to write in an edit, I "solved" my problem.

Comment: Yeah, this kind of "divine intervention" happens to me too every once in a while but it's the most scaring thing when I think of production environments.

Comment: I agree with that, and that's what I'm afraid of... but I'm running out of time, so let's pray! :/